# Is it possible to add a custom channel on an image?

Tags: image, channel

I am trying to make a custom image format, that has custom channels. Essentially I am trying to store some metadata for each pixel but on the same image. I know each pixel has 4 channela, a,r,g,b. I was wondering if its possible to do something like a,r,g,b,z, where z is some new number I can set and get.

Anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: For what is that good for?

Comment: GeoTIFF supports tens of thousands of bands/channels - try Googling `gdal` and `GeoTIFF`.

Comment: Of course you can. Why wouldn't you be able to? Although perhaps I'm not understanding the question, because it seems rather obvious that you can.

Comment: How then can I do it?

Comment: Do you need to store a 4-byte float for each channel, or an 8-bit integer or a 16-bit integer? Do you need much more metadata for the whole image than its width and height and the number of channels? Do you understand that the image will not be generally useable by any software other than your own?

Comment: lets say 4 byte for now.

Comment: And the other two questions I asked?

Comment: Well the amount of metadata I will add per pixel is related to do the width and height of the image. I can't say how much yet, so for now 4 bytes. Also I want it so the image is still readable by other programs, it just ignores this new channel.

Answer (score 1):

Most programs, i.e. Photoshop, GIMP, ImageMagick and the OSX Finder will ignore extraneous data at the end of JPEG, PNG or GIF images, so you could potentially add one or more extra channels of data to the end of such files - **WITH THE PROVISO** that you don't let them write the files when they will promptly lose all your appended data.

So, bearing that in mind you could generate an extra channel/band of data with ImageMagick and append it to the end of the normal RGBA image. So, let's create a red-yellow gradient as a conventional PNG image. You could equally use a JPEG or TIFF.

```
convert -size 256x256 gradient:red-yellow.png
```

[image]

and that is 935 bytes on my machine.

Now create a checkerboard pattern the same size and a single channel, i.e. grayscale to simulate your *"extra channel"*, and append it to the end of the PNG file:

```
convert -size 256x256 pattern:checkerboard -depth 8 gray:- >> image.png
```

Now the PNG file is 66,471 bytes but still viewable. So, to extract your extra channel, we need to determine that the greyscale image is 256x256 bytes, i.e. 65,536 bytes and subtract that from 66,471 to get 935 bytes which is the offset to our binary checkerboard. We can now read it in like this and make it into a PNG or JPEG:

```
convert -size 256x256+935 -depth 8 gray:image.png checkerboard.png
```

and you get your checkerboard out:

[image]

If you want to store a 4-byte float for each pixel, rather than the 8bit greyscale i used, you need to use

```
-define quantum:format=floating-point
```

and

```
-depth 32
```

and remember that your image size is HxWx4 bytes when calculating the offset.

ImageMagick is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX (preferably using `homebrew`) and Windows from [here](http://imagemagick.org).

Yes, this is an ugly hack, but no uglier than the original question :-)